# Why a current currying loop isn't affected by any force when it is placed in a uniform magnetic field,whereas it may get attracted to another loop?

Tags: electromagnetism

In a uniform magnetic field, a current currying coil will experience no force, however, when a current curring coil is placed opposite to another current currying coil, it can get attracted or repelled, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your question is for a circular current, but the circular current is the magnetic dipole at a bit of a distance, so I will consider a small magnet.
Moreover, i will use an old-fashioned expression.

Suppose there is a magnetic pole of $m_N$[Wb] on the N-pole side of the magnet and a magnetic pole of $m_S$[Wb] on the S-pole side. Let ${\vec{H}_N}$[A/m] and ${\vec{H}_S}$[A/m] be the external magnetic fields at each position.
[image]

The force that each magnetic pole receives from the external magnetic field is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\vec{F}_N&=m_N\vec{H}_N, \\
\vec{F}_S&=m_S\vec{H}_S
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Since there is probably no single magnetic pole in this world, the exact equality
\begin{equation}
m_N+m_S\equiv 0,
\end{equation}
always holds. Also, by the condition of a uniform magnetic field,
\begin{equation}
\vec{H}_N=\vec{H}_S.
\end{equation}
As a result,
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}_N+\vec{F}_S=\vec{0}.
\end{equation}
This means that the magnet is subject to rotational force but not translational force.

If the external magnetic field is not a uniform field case,
then $\vec{H}_N\neq\vec{H}_S$ and thus we get $\vec{F}_N+\vec{F}_S\neq\vec{0}$.

Comment: So, it experiences a force in the second case cause the magnetic field it experiences from the other loop isn't uniform, right?

Comment: @Jack, my answer is "yes". Sorry for the shortness of my English.

Answer (score 1):

When a current carrying loop is placed in a uniform magnetic field, the force at diametrically opposite points of the loop is opposite in direction and equal in magnitude. Thus, the two forces balance and the net force is zero. The only effect it can cause is that it may stretch the loop a bit.

However, when the current carrying loop is placed near another loop, it experiences a force as the magnetic field lines from the second loop crosses with the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field from the second coil is NOT "a uniform magnetic field".